# What happens when you burn salt in paraffin

Tags: salt

My 9 year-old son and I tried to do some extremely amateur flame testing...

We lit a paraffin burner [a little tin of paraffin jelly that came with a marshmallow 'smores' kit!] and sprinkled on about a teaspoon of salt. We got a brief yellow flame (as expected), which dimmed to blue. Then we simply let it burn for a while outside.

After a couple of hours, when it had all cooled down, we discovered that the salt had coalesced into a kind of mass. We removed it and found that it had the consistency of chewing gum. What was left behind was a clear, non-viscous liquid which smelled of paraffin.

We hoped to replicate the flame experiment, using more salt and the 'leftover paraffin' liquid. However, we found that the liquid is non-flammable!

I wondered if anyone could explain this. What exactly did the salt absorb that turned it into 'gum'? What liquid was left behind? And why is that liquid non-flammable?

(I'm delighted that we happened upon something strange and unexpected - much more interesting kitchen-chemistry than an Alka-Seltzer bottle rocket!)